# Downvoted questions due to lack of knowledge

Tags: discussion

I'm noticing quite a few questions recently that appear to have been downvoted, not because they are necessarily a poor question as per [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), but because the user clearly hasn't understood something fundamental to what they are trying to do.

*Some might refer to it as a 'stupid question'.*

One case today was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39701589/symfony2-execute-twig-inside-js-events) where the user totally misunderstood the technology he was using.

One could argue that it was a lack of research, but in this case the problem was more that the OP had miss-understood the tools at his disposal.

As far as I see it, someone's lack of knowledge shouldn't lead them to be downvoted providing they are asking a clear question that can be answered.

Shouldn't we be pointing the less techy users to documentation that might help bridge their knowledge gap? Or trying to constructively explain?

Or is this the wrong attitude to this type of question?

Comment: Can you provide a real-world example?

Comment: there's one in the question

Comment: @DevDonkey: "*As far as I see it, someone's lack of knowledge shouldn't lead them to be downvoted providing they are asking a clear question that can be answered.*" Then you're looking at things incorrectly. We do not downvote *people*; we downvote *posts*. Downvotes are not *personal*. If a question makes no sense or is otherwise time-wasting garbage, it doesn't matter if that is because the person asking the question is not knowledgeable or simply was very drunk when they posted it. It gets downvoted either way.

Comment: fair points.  I think my view of downvoting might have been slightly misaligned.

Answer (score 13):

If someone fundamentally doesn't understand the entire technology that they're using then trying to really answer their question is almost certainly going to be Too Broad, as an answer would need to explain a large amount of fundamentals of that technology in order for the answer to be understood.

Also keep in mind that the primary metric for voting on posts is whether or not the question is "useful".  That someone feels that a question isn't useful given that it's asking something nonsensical as a result of a fundamental misunderstanding of what the technology even is seems rather reasonable to me.