# How to be helpful in the scenario: users who simply lack knowledge of domain terminology?

Tags: discussion, bad-questions

I regularly encounter questions (often determined to be low quality) in which the asker posts the question **only** because they lack the requisite terminology (keyword) knowledge of the context domain that would otherwise enable them to effectively research on their own and find the answer. (One could argue that this is essentially the case for **every** question for which there is relevant information that's both indexed and accessible from some search engine — perhaps even every question that's been asked on the site: it is the nature of asking.)

In the case I describe, it's not that the asker isn't incredibly intelligent or lacks motivation, etc. — rather, the nature of the knowledge sought is that (statistically) it is only obtained through exposure/experience that the asker lacks.

Often I see these questions downvoted and/or closed without any helpful knowledge path forward for the asker (reasons like: needs more focus/clarity/etc.). If it were in the asker's power to provide that information, then surely they would in an effort of obtaining useful information toward their objective. (I recognize that motivation is impossible to determine on our part and that there are genuinely **plenty** of low-quality questions due to laziness, etc.)

This question isn't about downvoting:

- [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252677/438273)
- [Downvoted questions due to lack of knowledge [duplicate]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335255/438273)

and it's also not about triaging/closing:

- [How to triage a question that demonstrates profound lack of knowledge [duplicate]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344832/438273)

If the one wanting to help prefers to engage at a lower level of empathy and/or effort, that's out of scope here. (No judgement from me.)

Rather, this question I am asking is about understanding how I/we can be more empathetic/helpful in cases when an answer perhaps isn't possible, but generalized (yet context-relevant) information can be imparted to the asker (e.g. sharing a link to a wiki page related to some detail in the context of the information in the question).

I suppose my question could be worded this way: When (from our perspective) an asker isn't capable of adequately communicating in order to obtain the knowledge they seek (the asker's perspective: query-based research fails to yield the target information), how can we empathetically help expedite their journey on a platform that's so centered around this mechanism?

---

Apologies if this seems too open-ended/subjective: I genuinely just want to be a better participant in knowledge-sharing.

Comment: This might be a language barrier issue on my side, but what do you mean by "empathetically help" and similar? The *helpful* thing to do seems to be to drop a comment pointing to auxiliary information. Not sure where empathy comes into this (or is missing in the first place).

Comment: Of course you do, but Stack Overflow is for people who *did* inform themselves properly before they get stuck. The people you are talking about here really did not properly study the subject material before they started to blunder ahead. As such the site is absolutely not geared towards the kind of assistance you want to give; it would even be abuse of comments to provide your help there. That being said, I don't believe anyone would flag a comment which was created out of empathy.

Comment: not  for all topics are online sources available, so you get always questions about concepts, that must be discussed, but SO can not properly handle such questions, As Moderation and administration doesn't allow length discussions about ideas or minute nitpicking. The question should be asked, even when you get downvoted or closed, with some luck you find a nice person who answers

Comment: Do you have an example?  I have asked a couple of questions on here where I explained what I was seeing without knowing exactly where it was coming from, and got very helpful replies pointing me to in-depth answers that already existed.  If I had known to search for, e.g., "list comprehension variable scope leaks in python 2" I would have found it on my own, but I didn't.

Comment: For illustration, can you add one or more examples of such questions? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now.)

Comment: If you cannot provide a full answer, but have something of value - leave a comment. Something like, "See if this link is helpful" or "Google 'this that thing'".

Comment: This is an excellent question and you explained the scenario very well.  I've been in this situation and it's incredibly frustrating to be stuck and not know even know what question to ask because I lack domain knowledge and vocabulary. You're spot on that empathy is useful when answering some questions.

Comment: I am in this stage now. Thank you, OP for writing about this. SO community should definitely change its attitude toward helping newbies. Of course, people are helpful here, but the way this community treats those who don't even get the right terminology must change. We come here because we couldn't find the answer elsewhere, we are already in despair and then downvoted here. People should at least try to point at the right decision if not the answer.

Comment: @Gimby Sometimes it can be hard to do the necessary research when you don't have the right terminology. It's an "unknown unknowns" problem.

Comment: "what do you mean by 'empathetically help'" @MisterMiyagi Empathy is understanding of the experience of someone else in their frame of reference. It's especially relevant when communicating with someone on a different level. E.g.  answering differently to a young child vs a PhD candidate, based on their perspective. Or alternatively, you could choose to make no such concession, and provide the same answer regardless of background.

Comment: @PaulDraper I know what empathy is. I am not sure what "empathetically help" is supposed to mean concretely in this context. We generally don't know whether we are dealing with a PhD candidate or a freshman here, for example. And we generally try to treat questions as targeted at anyone who might ask them. Can you perhaps give a - synthetic or real - example in the context of [so]?

Answer (score 30):

Either we have an existing Q&A on that subject or we don't.

- If we do then we can duplicate the question. The OP then gets pointed to a question that hopefully contains the right terminology and an answer that demonstrates it.
- If we don't then there's nothing wrong with explaining the right terminology and writing an answer that demonstrates it.

Comment: There is still a third case where we only can *guess* at what the question really is, and where we can only recognize that they've gone the wrong way somewhere on the road. From what I understand from the question here, it's mainly(?) about cases where the asker isn't able to actually formulate their question, because of this lack of formal knowledge. "*this question I am asking is about understanding how I/we can be more empathetic/helpful **in cases when an answer perhaps isn't possible***" (emphasizes mine).

Comment: @Kaiido We aren't mind-readers. We can only go with what's presented by the asker. And if that isn't enough to make a good answerable question, it should be closed. Fin.

Comment: If the question is new and understandable but uses wrong terminology, I think it is better to edit in proper terminology (rather, edit so that the terminology *is used* properly) - as long as this doesn't obfuscate the question (i.e. by making it less obvious *why OP would be confused*).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel .. true enough, except that we answer questions from *our* perspective, and if a question can be interpreted multiple ways, you can bet that it *will* be. I'm sure there will be some questions where the intent is clear despite terminology, but there will be a grey area that some questions fall into as well. I feel that editing the question is still the right approach, but perhaps only after confirming with the OP in comments. Or maybe even after an answer has been selected.

Comment: @IanKemp sure, my comment just says that this answer misses the point of the question which is precisely about what behavior we should adopt when facing such question that can't/shouldn't be answered. Your comment does answer this case with your own view, that should be an answer not a comment here. (By the way, to make things clear about my take on this, most of the time I'll just VTC and move on, but I sometimes also feel sympathetic enough to leave a comment pointing the asker to where I believe they should start looking. Depends on the situation, the tone of the asker, my cat's mood, etc.)

Answer (score 14):

> When (from our perspective) an asker isn't capable of adequately communicating in order to obtain the knowledge they seek (the asker's perspective: query-based research fails to yield the target information), how can we empathetically help expedite their journey on a platform that's so centered around this mechanism?

Allow me to challenge the framing of this question by asking a different one:

Is that what Stack Overflow is *for*?

Consider an alternative definition of what it means for Stack Overflow to "work".

You have a problem. You search for a solution, using whatever you can say to explain it.

Stack Overflow is "working" if that search results in a question that represents your problem and has an answer for it. That is, if SO already solved your problem and it provided you the solution in a way you could find, that is when Stack Overflow is working as intended. No user-interaction needed.

Stack Overflow is not working if there is no matching question that could be found by reasonable search criteria. To allow SO to work better in the future, we allow people to create a question and give someone the opportunity to answer it (or mark it as a duplicate, as a sign post to the actual answer). This allows SO to work for any future user who has that question.

To put it simply, we allow questions and answers in an effort to *fix* a problem in Stack Overflow. This means that asking a question and getting an answer is useful to Stack Overflow only to the extent that this question/answer can be found by someone else who searches for that problem.

If a person's problem is "I don't have the words to explain my problem," then that becomes much less likely. While there are some terminology questions that are often misunderstood in similar ways, in a lot of cases of a near-complete lack of understanding, there are infinitely many ways a user might ask about the same misunderstanding.

Such a question is unfindable by reasonable searches. And therefore, people who have a similar problem won't be able to find the Q&A. That means the question is not helping Stack Overflow "work".

So within this re-framing of the question, you're effectively asking to help a user in a way that isn't helping Stack Overflow function in accord with its primary purpose.

I would perhaps suggest that this is not an activity worthy of your time. If you want to help make SO work better, it would be a better use of your time to find questions that *do* represent good usage of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Finally, someone who actually understands how this site is intended to work. Apparently even the moderators don't remember nowadays.

Comment: This is exactly why such questions should be kept. A user who doesn't know the technical jargon to frame their question is probably going to try to explain it in the same words that others in their situation will use to search for the answer in the future.

Comment: I have encountered *numerous* cases where the same question keeps getting re-asked in different ways, and none of them are a sensible way (from the technical jargon perspective). If we notice people "using the same words" to describe the same problem, we should accommodate that for the sake of searchability, even if those words aren't the best choice. However, if everyone who has the problem is flailing around desperately to describe it, then by all means just point them at a canonical - prepare one yourself if you have to. That's better than stretching to call a common misconception a "typo".

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede: "*A user who doesn't know the technical jargon to frame their question is probably going to try to explain it in the same words that others in their situation will use to search for the answer in the future.*" Citation needed. I've seen numerous cases of people misunderstanding the same thing where they describe it in *different* wrong ways. My (long) experience on this site and others is that what you're describing is not especially common and generally already has a duplicate that they can be pointed to.

Comment: @NicolBolas So keep them all. It's audacious hubris to think human curators can do a better job than a search engine.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede: And how many of those should we have to sift through to find a question that is answerable? Our time and patience is not infinite. One of the goals of SO is to more efficiently use the time of people willing to donate their expertise by reducing the amount of cruft they have to go through to find an interesting question. "Keep them all" doesn't help anybody; even the person asking the question will eventually lose because people with domain knowledge will see SO as not worth their time. Your suggestion does not scale; it only works if you look at a single, individual thing.

Comment: @NicolBolas *You* don't have to sift through any of them; a search engine can do that. People with domain knowledge *already* don't consider SO worth their time. The vast majority of developers refuse to use this site because of the super-aggressive question closure.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Yes the site sees almost no traffic nowadays.

Answer (score 10):

Unless the subject domain is programming itself (e.g. the OP is trying to write a tool for programmers, an IDE, a compiler, an interpreter, a parser, etc.), then questions about domain knowledge are simply off-topic – regardless of whether the OP knows that their question is about domain knowledge or not.

If the OP is writing a banking system, but does not know the term "withdrawal", then the correct thing to do is to close the question as off-topic, since banking is not on-topic on Stack Overflow. The old "[boat programming](https://web.archive.org/web/20100426125115/http://www.mattmcdole.com/boat/)" mantra applies: not every question that appears *during* programming is a question *about* programming.

Sometimes, it is not obvious that this is the case, though. I myself have answered many questions, where my answer then sparked a comment by the OP, to which I responded either with an edit or a comment, which sparked another comment by the OP, and so on, and it only became clear after several rounds of back and forth that the OP's struggles had nothing to do with programming at all, but they simply didn't understand the domain problem they were trying to solve.

A real example I have seen is where the OP asks about the behavior of `if` statements, gets an answer, then changes the question to ask about logical operators, gets an answer, then changes the question to ask about comparison operators, gets an answer, then changes the question again, and in the end, it turns out that what they are trying to do is determining whether two rectangles overlap, and they simply do not understand what "overlap" means.

I've seen questions where the OP is writing a physics simulation and their problem is that they don't understand the physics, or they want to write an equation solver but don't know how to solve an equation, etc. None of these are programming problems.

If the OP does not understand the problem domain or does not know terms of the problem domain, that is a business domain problem, not a programming problem (unless the business domain happens to be programming or programs, e.g. when writing an IDE or a parser). And there is nothing that can be done in terms of programming to fix that, the OP needs to study the problem domain.

Comment: Further boat programming reference: at 1 h 02 min 43 secs in [episode 50 of the Stack Overflow podcast](https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-podcast-28), classic series (2009-04-21).

Comment: I'm not sure if "domain" from the OP's perspective might still mean programming. In other words, OP might be asking: What to do about posts where the poster lacks the right programming domain knowledge? Eg a poster asking about classes that can use each other's code, but not realizing they are describing inheritance or polymorpism.

Comment: In your real example where a user repeatedly edits the question, don't indulge their idiocy. Mod-flag and explain what's going on so that the question can be locked or closed.

Comment: "asks about the behavior of if statements, gets an answer, then changes the question" If the original question was asked, answered and has value, it's time to move on.  (Although it's hard for me to imagine that someone with this task could have a real question about "the behavior of if statements" that isn't a duplicate.) Above all else, Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum.

Comment: Non-"realistic" Answer to OP's Qt (Question)... "Writing a Tool (that will be useful for Programmers, OK, nice Project...!) or writing some Banking Software (and don't know the Term "withdrawal", ah-ah...!, how did they get the job...!?)", = Tasks for experienced Developers who will know how to tackle any new Prog-Lang by first reading the Documentation and using the correct Terminology if they need any Searching... // OP's Qt is more about "Newbies" (to all Programming) who can't even identify `nested` as the "magic" word if they want to find out about "a loop in a loop"...

Answer (score 4):

I handle this with a comment and possibly an extra tag. My comment might say something like "your class of problem is, I guess, called ’gaps-and-islands.'"

It's usually not a good use of my time to prepare an answer that begins with a reformulation of the problem, because such questions often get closed before I can post my answer.

Answer (score 3):

We certainly don't want to spoon-feed OPs who Lack Minimal Understanding and have a cargo-cult approach to coding. However, sometimes we get sincere questions from OPs who have studied tutorials and tried to do proper research before posting a question, but they have gaps in their knowledge that prevented them from finding the information they need. It's an "unknown unknowns" problem.

In that situation, a short comment that mentions relevant
keywords can set the OP on the right track. They may then be able to solve their problem themself, and perhaps post a self-answer. Or they may be able to revise their (unanswered) question to make it a better fit for the Stack Overflow model.

Comment: We got rid of LMU as a close reason, in my understanding, because Stack Overflow is supposed to be about the questions rather than the askers. The problem isn't that the asker is LMU; the problem is that the L of MU makes the question *unclear* (because it doesn't lead to a sensible specification for the behaviour of the code). If the problem is just "you didn't read the documentation", well - even then, there might be something to be gained from having experts on SO rephrase and contextualize.

Comment: @Karl Fair points, but I'm talking about OPs who have read the docs, and understand what they're trying to accomplish, but they're trying to "re-invent the wheel". If we tell them the name of the wheel then they can do further research. That may lead them to solving the problem themself, or if they still can't figure it out they can modify the question (or ask a fresh one) about a specific difficulty they have implementing the algorithm.

Comment: Fair. This is an extremely common problem - there are two fundamentally different ways to approach the question: "How do I do <thing that this code is supposed to be doing>?" and "What is wrong with this code?" These are basically always two different questions and I have come to the conclusion that *we need to determine which one OP wants, first* and then proceed accordingly.

Comment: @Karl Why not both? ;) I like to say "your code doesn't do what you expect because of XYZ" and show how to fix that. But if there's a better approach (more readable &/or more efficient) I like to show that too. That helps the OP and it's likely to help more future readers than an answer that just fixes the broken code, or just shows the better solution.

Comment: Because we want *focused* questions, and search results that correspond to expectations. If the title is "how do I x?" and the OP indeed is primarily interested in getting x done, then the broken attempt at x-ing is often a net negative to the question. If the title is "why doesn't this work?" and the OP clearly wants debugging help, then the fact that it's part of an attempt at x-ing often makes the MRE insufficiently M. It needs to be retitled in a way that categorizes the non-working "this", to have any hope of being searchable.

Comment: Further, *either or both* of those questions might be a common duplicate. If they aren't, sometimes they *should* be - but that's a lot harder for the debugging questions, because it takes the answerers *noticing* a pattern of people making the same mistake, gathering up the dupes in wildly varying contexts, and figuring out how to canonicalize it. But if the question is going to end up being about debugging, you can always point at solutions to the overall problem in a comment, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 3):

#### Stack Overflow is first and foremost about the questions, not the askers.

Helping OP with a practical problem is a side effect of the process. Ideally, this encourages more questions in the future, selectively from those who do a better job of asking them. *Trying* to ensure that OP is helped by the answer, is part of QC on the answer: good answers are ones that can be understood by someone who would need the question answered. However, this can only happen once the question is ascertained.

So, we go through the *usual* steps.

Is it possible to figure out what OP actually wants the code to do? If not, downvote, mark as unclear, move on. This can happen because the terminology is a total mess. Some people can't be helped out in this format, and need to start over from scratch and *learn the fundamentals properly*. Stack Overflow is the wrong medium for that.

Does OP's goal make sense? If the actual question asks to do the impossible, it's time for comment feedback to figure out if there's an XY problem. If there's an XY problem, we can edit the question to be about the Y, then iterate if there are any more issues. Otherwise, we can figure out how OP got in this mess in the first place - which might prompt an entirely new question, but this one should probably be closed. It's very hard to justify a question where the answer is "it is not possible". (Maybe by reworking it into a question about the *cause* of the impossibility?)

If the question asks to do something that's merely *strange* in context ("I tried to concatenate a literal backslash and a lowercase n, and it didn't turn into a newline; why not?"), then *search extensively for a dupe*. There's actually a pretty good chance that someone has previously asked a reasonably close question that makes the request make sense in a different context ("I downloaded data that embedded text strings in another format and had to use escape sequences for nonprintable characters to avoid breaking the format; now I've parsed the file and extracted those strings; how can I elegantly convert the sequences into what they represent?").<sup>1</sup>

If the goal is comprehensible and reasonable, but there is just a lot of misused terminology (calling things "commands" that aren't, or talking about "calling" things to mean accessing data structures, or seeking to "import" data are common ones), then just clean it up. Use *correct* terminology where possible, but balance that against preserving OP's *model* of the problem. Make the title as searchable as possible. I add synonyms in parentheses sometimes, e.g. [How do I concatenate (join) items in a list to a single string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580) . That's been a useful canonical for years, but experts being able to find the canonical for dupe-hammering is only half the equation. A lot of people who want to solve this problem won't know the word `concatenate`. Others may assume that `join` is too pedestrian to actually be found by search engines or used by technical authors. I say, put them both. (After all, the actual method is called `.join`!)

1. I'm not just making this example up. I closed a *lot* of questions as duplicates of [Process escape sequences in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539) in the last few days.

Answer (score 2):

**If the poster cannot adequately articulate a question,** it will be closed for "Needs details or clarity."

Example: Q: "How do I make a computer add numbers?"

**If the poster cannot adequately understand the answer,** that's okay because the Q&A still happened and will be available to other visitors. If you want, you can further explain basic concepts, start a discussion, etc. But a correct answer has been given.

Example: Q: "Why is this PostgreSQL update not working?" A: "There is a unique constraint, and the query duplicates values."

Comment: Hum..., "*not working*" should automatically trigger the `Close` + `Needs details or clarity` anyway...!